# WooCommerce Cant Change Shop Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to create a custom template for the shop page using WooCommerce, ive tried editing a lot of the files, it was mentioned that it uses the archive-product.php file but thats doesnt seem to work, ive changed the template in the page editing mode and that doesnt work either, i have gone through the settings menu to see if there was a option to change the page but i did not see one. So which file controls the shop page. I will make a copy of the file into my custom theme once i can see any changes taking effect from the original files.

Edit: This is the archive-product.php file, i can throw in a h1 tag but when i view it on the front end the text wont display so i assume this is the incorrect file, yet ive gone through every file here and dropped that hello message in, and nothing is found on the front end [screenshot of code](http://prntscr.com/8vhea2)

Comment: Can you show what you've changed, edited. Show some code so that the people could help you.

Comment: normally i would show code but theres nothing to really show for this is there? essentially its figuring out which is the right file thats being used, if you see this screenshot of the file structure: http://prntscr.com/8vhdnx

Comment: When templating the woocommerce in your theme you shouldn't touch any file in the plugin, since all those edits will be gone once you update the plugin. Read this: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: i have read this already, i will make the copy file in my theme once i know it works, although i had tried that earlier. when i know which file is allowing me to make changes ill move it to the custom theme and apply the changes there.

Comment: The default shop page that displays the products in the loop is located in `archive-product.php` file. Once you've created woocommerce folder, you can copy the templates folder and edit any file you like, the changes should be visible immediately.

Comment: thats the problem im having, it should allow me to see the changes but its not. if you see this screenshot, i have the woocommerce folder and template folders with the archive-product.php there: http://prntscr.com/8vhi5d   and the second screenshot shows the h1 hello tags i dropped in, however even searching the front end i cant find these tags. http://prntscr.com/8vhiv3

Comment: Don't put templates folder inside woocommerce folder. Just put all the folders and files from the templates folder directly to the woocommerce folder. So that your path is `/dragoncove/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. Currently it's `/dragoncove/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`, and this is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to modify `content-product.php`  template, this is the template that `archive-product.php` uses to display the products .

Comment: yes, if i change the file i moved to my theme it doesnt work at all however if i edit the version in the woocommerce plugin version it outputs like this : http://prntscr.com/8viu6s   however the archive-product doesnt register any changes no matter which one i open.